# Prevent mysqldump produces intermediate files

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dump, rr

Mysqldump produces intermediate files. How do I prevent these files?


- my code:

```
mysqldump -v --single-transaction --quick mydb > dump.sql
```

- result:

```
7.7G  13:49  dump-rr-rr-rr-rr.sql
6.7G  13:42  dump-rr-rr-rr.sql
3.4G  13:20  dump-rr-rr.sql
1.7G  13:10  dump-rr.sql
668M  13:05  dump.sql       <--- I only want this file with all data
```

I'm using: ubuntu18.04, mariadb10.2.4, mysqldump10.13

Comment: mysqldump does not produce those files.

Comment: I'm using mysqldump for 4 databases (same mysqldump script), but one of them produces those files.

Comment: mysqldump does not touch any files by itself, it just writes to standard output. So if you redirect with "... > dump.sql" it only writes to that file.

There must be something else touching those files ...